# CocoaPods: Creating Public Pod depending on Private Pod trunk push not working

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I am creating a public pod that depends on a private pod (can be installed from external Spec in public GitHub).

When I am linting my `.podspec` file, it works fine without any issue.

`pod lib lint --sources='https://github.com/PRIVATE_REPO_GIT/Specs.git,https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git' --verbose --no-clean`

But when I try to `pod trunk push` my pod, it show the below error.

> -> MY_POD_NAME (1.0.0)
> - ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Unable to find a specification for `PRIVATE_REPO_POD` depended upon by
> `MY_POD_NAME`

**Is it possible to create a pod with a depending pod that is private?**
Since we need our users to get our repo and the dependent repo with adding one line in `.podfile` and we done this before but the libraries were not private.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.

`pod trunk push` is intended to make pods available for public usage. The command fails since that won't be the case if there is a private dependency.

Any pod with private dependencies should also be private only.